# login to subdomain from another subdomain

Tags: authentication, subdomain, mason

I have one site `parent1.site.com`, and I am logged in and I have authentication cookie with domain `parent1.site.com`.

Is there way so that I can use that cookie, for automatically getting logged in another site, say for example `parent2.site.com` ?

Suppose I can not change domain of authentication cookie of `parent1.amazon.com`. I have tried to put the default domain of `parent2.amazon.com` as `parent1.amazon.com`, but that is not working.

I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the solution that is (or it was) integrated in facebook. Once you are login in one of your domains use javascript to create an iframe and load a page from the other one. Then just set cookies in new page loaded in the iframe. It is a dummy and tricky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to simulate the "trusted" cookie. Your 2 domain should recognize the cookie from the 1 domain and do job.